# On animations with mathematica.se logo

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Yesterday I posted [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11880/219) which, as Mr.Wizard noted, lacks constructivity. I have to agree with this, and when I started to think on editing I realized that there are actually **three** options which are of interest for me at least.

1. Animated process of construction from scratch, as it is described in Verbeia's blog post.
2. Animated morphing of original pentagonal star to the current heptagonal one (thanks to J.M.'s comment)
3. Some less fussy, a tranquil animation of the logo itself, more suitable for placing on webpages.

So, how should I go about this? The possibilities are:

1. Include all three options in one question.
2. Incorporate items 1 and 2 together and separate number 3.
3. Three separate questions? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't considered this extensively but I'm inclined to option #1.  I think points one and two would make the question "concrete" enough to avoid closure, and if anyone wants to tackle the third they can.  Of course, if the third is your primary focus this may not be acceptable.  I see the third as being a bit too open ended by itself, but so was this question and nobody closed it:

[Artistic image vectorization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8507/121)